# How to set slave IP Modbus TCP with modbus4j?

Tags: java, ip, slave, modbus

I am programming a java application using `modbus4j`.

I would read `%MW` of `M258` controller from PC java application.

In the `modbus4j` project I found this sample:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        IpParameters params = new IpParameters();
        params.setHost("localhost");
        params.setPort(502);

        ModbusMaster master = new ModbusFactory().createTcpMaster(params, false);
        master.init();

        System.out.println(master.testSlaveNode(5));

        // Define the point locator.
        ModbusLocator loc = new ModbusLocator(1, RegisterRange.HOLDING_REGISTER, 0, DataType.TWO_BYTE_INT_UNSIGNED);

        // Set the point value
        master.setValue(loc, 1800);

        // Get the point value
        System.out.println(master.getValue(loc));
    }
}
```

But I do not know how can assign the IP to the slave.

In this sample I only can see a `slaveID` (int), but not the ***slave IP***.

***Do you know how can I write the slave IP?***

Comment: I believe in params.setHost(" "), this is where you will want to define the slave IP.  Are you asking what format to enter the IP?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes, my question is How can I define the slave IP? If, for example, I want to read some %MW of one slave with IP = 192.168.10.20, Can I define this IP to the slave with: params.setHost("192.168.10.20")?

Comment: I have not done this using Java before.  What happens when you try the above format?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I can confirm that your are right, with params.setHost("slaveIP") I can define the slave IP. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following 2 lines set the IP a Port of the slave device

```
params.setHost("localhost");
params.setPort(502);
```